# How callback function's parameters work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, higher-order-functions

So I'm trying to understand functional programming and higher order functions in specific. What I never clearly understood, was how callback function's parameters have a connection to, for example, an array?

To be more clear, let's take this code example:

```
var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];

friends.forEach(function (eachName, index){
console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); // 1. Mike, 2. Stacy, 3. Andy, 4. Rick
});
```

How a callback parameter `eachName` knows that it means to return the item from array and `index` is supposed to return an index of array? How the connection between an array and callback parameter works?

Comment: `forEach` is calling your callback function, passing `"Mike", 0` etc. as arguments…

Comment: `forEach` has nothing to do with functional programming. Don't use it.

Comment: @Bergi what about `map`?

Comment: @Limpuls Yes, much better :-) The explanation is the same though - the callback doesn't know it, the array method just does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `forEach` method is calling or invoking your callback function. To be more specific let's see how the forEach work.

```
function forEach(arr, func) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    func(arr[i], i);
  }
}
```

Now you can do  something like this.

```js
function forEach(arr, func) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    func(arr[i], i);
  }
}

var cars = ["BMW", "Tata Nano", "Lamborghini"];

forEach(cars, function (car, index) {
  alert(car + " "  + index);
});
```

Comment: [Insert caveat about iterating over arrays using `for..in` here…]

Comment: We can also use for in loop for an array because array is basically object in which all the indexes are stored according to numbers.

Comment: Okay, okay, I'll insert the actual caveat: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/476)

Comment: Now I understand. And thanks for clearing things out about `for..in`. I'm just wondering, in the `func(arr[i], i);` second parameter `i` works as iterator for index of the element in array because we used the variable in `arr[i]`? How it knows that it's supposed to be an index when we call the function?

Comment: i don't under stand your question. Can you be more clear

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out myself, that `i` is defined in the for loop body as 0 and is incremented by one each time and so is used for indexing elements in array? So if `i` variable is used as `arr[i]`, we get each item, but if we just use parameter `i`, it's the same as just typing [0], [1], etc and we get the index only. Am I right? That's what I wanted to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The API does it for you. In this case, [`array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)'s callback is always set to accept 3 arguments: the current item, the current item's index in the array, and the array itself.

One example of an API that has a different argument signature is [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It is set to accept 4 arguments: The accumulator, the current item, the current item's index and the array itself.

Comment: Oh, I never knew that is just the API that is so designed. I thought you can throw whatever parameters you want and that's why I was wondering how it works after that. But if it's programmed in to take 3 arguments and those arguments are fixed, then it makes sense. Could you link me to an article or something for more information on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Limpuls MDN is a good resource. Standard function rules apply. For instance, `function.bind` can alter the context and prepend fixed arguments. Arrow functions also apply their "this-less" nature.

Comment: So if we want to use our own custom made higher order function and not built-in one, like `forEach`, we can decide how many parameters it can have and what they will be (like I said in my prev post, program them in and make fixed, like first argument will be accumulator, second currentIndex and so on) by using `.bind`?